# One of the pages of my application is displayed by a code

Tags: python, django

Help me by advice, please. When I go to one of the pages, its code is displayed, in inspector I see, that all the code is taken in the `<pre>` tag, although the code does not have this tag. How can this be overcome? Thanks in advance!
    **navbar:**

```
python    
<li {% if 'about' in request.path %} class="active" {% else %} {% endif %}><a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
```

**Main url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', include("pages.urls")),
    ...
```

**Url of app pages:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('about', views.about, name = "about"),
    ...
```

I'm at first here, don't know, maybe page with code shold be placed separately

**About page:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} About {% endblock %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% include "partials/_header_internal.html" %}

<div class="site-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0 order-lg-2">
                <img src="{% static 'images/hero_2.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 mr-auto">
                <h2>Car Company</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit suscipit, repudiandae similique
                    accusantium eius nulla quam laudantium sequi.</p>
                <p>Debitis voluptates corporis saepe molestias tenetur ab quae, quo earum commodi, laborum dolore, fuga
                    aliquid delectus cum ipsa?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="site-section bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mb-5 section-2-title">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <span class="text-primary">Our Team</span>
                <h2 class="mb-4">Meet Our Team</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis provident eius ratione velit,
                    voluptas laborum nemo quas ad necessitatibus placeat?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row align-items-stretch">
            {% if managers %}
            {% for manager in managers %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-5">
                <div class="post-entry-1 h-100 person-1">

                    <img src="{{ manager.photo.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">

                    <div class="post-entry-1-contents">
                        <span class="meta">Manager</span>
                        <h2>{{ manager.name }}</h2>
                        <p>{{ manager.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>No Managers Aviable</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="site-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <img src="{% static 'images/hero_1.jpg' %}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto">
                <h2>Our History</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit suscipit, repudiandae similique
                    accusantium eius nulla quam laudantium sequi.</p>
                <p>Debitis voluptates corporis saepe molestias tenetur ab quae, quo earum commodi, laborum dolore, fuga
                    aliquid delectus cum ipsa?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container site-section mb-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
        <div class="col-7 text-center mb-5">
            <h2>How it works</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo assumenda, dolorum necessitatibus eius
                earum voluptates sed!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="how-it-works d-flex">
        <div class="step">
            <span class="number"><span>01</span></span>
            <span class="caption">Time &amp; Place</span>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <span class="number"><span>02</span></span>
            <span class="caption">Car</span>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <span class="number"><span>03</span></span>
            <span class="caption">Details</span>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <span class="number"><span>04</span></span>
            <span class="caption">Checkout</span>
        </div>
        <div class="step">
            <span class="number"><span>05</span></span>
            <span class="caption">Done</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Base.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:300,400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'fonts/icomoon/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/bootstrap-datepicker.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/jquery.fancybox.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/owl.theme.default.min.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/aos.css' %}"/>    
    <!-- main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>


    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".site-navbar-target" data-offset="300">
    {% include "partials/_navbar.html" %}    
    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
    {% include "partials/_footer.html" %}

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.sticky.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fancybox.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.easing.1.3.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/aos.js' %}"></script>   

    <script src="{% static 'js/main.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**pages> views.py:**

```
from cars.models import CarsList
from carmanager.models import CarManager
from .cars_Info import vendor_list, models_list, engine_list, transmission_list
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from contacts.models import Contacts


def index(request):
    cars = CarsList.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)
    query = CarsList.objects.order_by("vendor")
    random_car = CarsList.objects.order_by('?')[0]

    orders = Contacts.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)
    random_orders = Contacts.objects.filter(is_published=True).order_by('?')[:3]  

    paginator = Paginator(cars, 3)
    page = request.GET.get("page")
    paged_cars = paginator.get_page(page)

    if "vendor" in request.GET:
        vendor = request.GET["vendor"]
        if vendor:
            query = query.filter(vendor__iexact=vendor)

    if "model" in request.GET:
        model = request.GET["model"]
        if model:
            query = query.filter(model__iexact=model)

    if "engine" in request.GET:
        engine = request.GET["engine"]
        if engine:
            query = query.filter(engine__iexact=engine)

    if "transmission" in request.GET:
        transmission = request.GET["transmission"]
        if transmission:
            query = query.filter(transmission__iexact=transmission)

    context = {
        "cars_all": cars,
        'cars': paged_cars,
        "vendor_list": vendor_list,
        "models_list": models_list,
        "engine_list": engine_list,
        "transmission_list": transmission_list,
        "search_cars": query,
        "request_value": request.GET,
        "rnd_car": random_car,
        "random_orders": random_orders
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)


def about(request):
    managers = CarManager.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)[:3]

    context = {
        'managers': managers,
    }

    data = {'title': "About Us"}
    return render(request, 'pages/about.html', context, data)


def services(request):
    data = {'title': "Our Services"}
    return render(request, 'pages/services.html', data)


def contact(request):
    data = {'title': "Contact Us"}
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', data)

def search(request):
    query = CarsList.objects.order_by("vendor")

    paginator = Paginator(query, 3)
    page = request.GET.get("page")
    paged_search_cars = paginator.get_page(page)

    if "vendor" in request.GET:
        vendor = request.GET["vendor"]
        if vendor:
            query = query.filter(vendor__iexact=vendor)

    if "model" in request.GET:
        model = request.GET["model"]
        if model:
            query = query.filter(model__iexact=model)

    if "engine" in request.GET:
        engine = request.GET["engine"]
        if engine:
            query = query.filter(engine__iexact=engine)

    if "transmission" in request.GET:
        transmission = request.GET["transmission"]
        if transmission:
            query = query.filter(transmission__iexact=transmission)

    context = {
        "search_cars": query,
        "paged_search_cars": paged_search_cars,
        "vendor_list": vendor_list,
        "models_list": models_list,
        "engine_list": engine_list,
        "transmission_list": transmission_list,        
        "request_value": request.GET

    }

    return render(request, 'pages/search.html', context)
```

Comment: We can't help unless you show us some details.  Start by showing us the html page template.

Comment: added about-page

Comment: can you paste your code differently? you have mixed code from different files in one while asking the question. Also, please explain a little bit what is the exact issue.

Comment: when I open in browser 1 of pages (about), I see onlly white page with html code, F12 - all code is in tag <pre>

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: views from app pages added

Comment: This problem is solved. I gave 1 excess parameter: `return render(request, 'pages/about.html', context, data)`

Comment: rewrited: `def about(request):
    managers = CarManager.objects.all().filter(is_published=True)[:3]

    context = {
        'managers': managers,
        'title': "About Us"
    }    
    return render(request, 'pages/about.html', context)`